# Option menu icon(3 dots) pushing other images present in toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

In my toolbar, there are 3 images on the left side which also include option menu icon. But the problem is my option menu icon is pushing the other two images and the view(horizontal line) which is present in the toolbar.

```
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_back"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_14dp"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/select_back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:clipChildren="false"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="@drawable/ripple"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/left_arrow">

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView

                    android:id="@+id/back_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/events"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16sp">


                </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>

            </LinearLayout>


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/calendar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/filter"
                android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/calender_vector">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/filter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/option"
                android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_filter">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/option"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_optionmenu"
                android:visibility="gone">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linear_back"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@color/edittext_grey"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

[image]

As you can left side of the toolbar, the view is getting pushed. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You try it like this :

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_back"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_14dp"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/select_back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:clipChildren="false"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="@drawable/ripple"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/left_arrow">

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView

                    android:id="@+id/back_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/events"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16sp">


                </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>

            </LinearLayout>


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/calendar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/filter"
                android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/calender_vector">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/filter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/option"
                android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_filter">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/option"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_optionmenu"
                android:visibility="gone">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>

       </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linear_back"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@color/edittext_grey"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```